# Unable to Ping SVI IP (VRF) interface from VM

Tags: cisco, vlan, vrf

I'm trying to figure out why I am unable to ping an IP associated with a VLAN in a VRF from my VM's directly attached to the same VLANs.  I can ping each interface on the switch directly using ping vrf centos 10.1x.1.1.  I can see the mac addresses in the vlan on the 3750X stack as well so I know there is connectivity.

```
ip vrf centos
rd 10.10.1.253:1
!
!
interface Vlan3011
ip vrf forwarding centos
ip address 10.11.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan3012
 ip vrf forwarding centos
 ip address 10.12.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan3013
 ip vrf forwarding centos
 ip address 10.13.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
!
end
```

Here's a bit more on the config -

VMware Hosts attached via DVS to trunk ports on Cisco 5548's which are connected via port channel trunk to a 3750X Stack.  the VRF config is on the 3750X stack since the 5548's do not have L3 enabled or licensed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could the hosts have a firewall that is blocking pings?

Comment: Can you ping anything else from the VMs, or is it just the SVI you can't ping?

Comment: I can ping other VM's on same VLAN (including other switches) just can not ping the SVI